# Como chamar um form e ocultar o anterior em C#?

Tags: c#

Estou no meio de projeto para faculdade e estou com dificuldade.

O sistema tem um `Form` principal e quando eu chamo o segundo `Form` o principal continua visível. Como faço para ocultar o `form` principal enquanto o segundo estiver aberto?

O código para chamar o segundo `form` e esse:

```
F_CalcSimples F_CalcSimples = new F_CalcSimples();

F_CalcSimples.ShowDialog();
```

Se alguém poder ajudar agradeço muito!

Answer (score 4):

Use a propriedade `Visible` do seu `form` principal que serve para retornar ou definir se um objeto esta visível, veja o exemplo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;

    Form2 meu_segundo_form = new Form2();
    meu_segundo_form.ShowDialog();

    this.Visible = true;
}
```

Mais informações [aqui](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Hiding_and_Showing_Forms_in_C_Sharp).

Mais sobre a propriedade [Visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff196785.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.Hide();
                frmTelaPrincipal novo = new frmTelaPrincipal();
                novo.Show();
        }
```

Comment: `novo.ShowDialog();` e em `seguida this.Show();`.